# Cannot access a property created

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ to SQL model that was used in my website. I've since converted the website to a web application and have the need to add a property to an entity.

I've tried adding the property using the designer, as well as regenerating the entity via server explorer.

In the .cs file I can see the public property JobTemplateName but when I try and access the property it doesn't show up. All other properties show, just not the new one. If I try I get a compiler error saying that Job doesn't contain a property called JobTemplateName.

Here is the code in the designer.cs

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="TemplateName", Storage="_JobTemplateName", DbType="NVarChar(400)")]
    public string JobTemplateName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._JobTemplateName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._JobTemplateName != value))
            {
                this.OnJobTemplateNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._JobTemplateName = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("JobTemplateName");
                this.OnJobTemplateNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hmm, OK. It appears that I have a database.designer.cs file and a database1.designer.cs file. Something is going wrong somewhere....

Comment: Is this all in one project, or do you have multiple projects? It sounds like the calling code is probably just looking at the old code...

Comment: It's all in one project, I think the 2 designer files is causing the issue. The code is looking at database.designer but the new properties only appear in database1.designer

Comment: Ah, this is the first I'd heard of that. How did you end up with two designer files? That does indeed sound like a bad starting point...

Comment: I'm not sure, although suspicions point to the conversion from website to web application. I'm now in the process of rebuilding the entire data context.

Comment: Righto. Sounds like that's probably the way to go :)

Comment: Just delete them, and let the IDE recreate it. If that fails, exclude the dbml file, and then include it again.